# Issue recalling method. unsure of where im going wrong

Tags: java, methods

Below is my code and I have notes beside where my errors are showing. Im unsure where I am going wrong when recalling my method or if that is even the issue.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HurlerUse
{
    static Hurler[] hurlerArray;

    // find lowest score (static method)    
    public static int findLow(Hurler[] hurlerArray)
    {
         for(int i = 0; i < hurlerArray.length; i++)
         {
            int lowest = 0;
            int index = 0;
            for(int j=0; j<hurlerArray.length; j++)
            {
                int current = hurlerArray[i].totalPoints();// issue with         my method 'totalPoints' 
            if(current < lowest)
            {
                lowest = current;
                index = i;
            }
        }
            return index;
    }


}


//main code
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Hurler[] hurlerArray = new Hurler[5];

    for (int i = 0; i <4; i++)
    {
        hurlerArray[i] = new Hurler();
        System.out.println ("Enter Hurler Name:");
        hurlerArray[i].setName(sc.nextLine()); 
        hurlerArray[i].setGoalsScored(sc.nextInt()); 
        System.out.println("Enter the hurler's goals scored");
        hurlerArray[i].setPointsScored(sc.nextInt()); 
        System.out.println("Enter the hurler's points scored");
    }

    for(int i=0;i< hurlerArray.length; i++)
    {
        hurlerArray[i] = new Hurler(MyName, MyGoalsScored, MyPointsScored);// issue with all 3 objects in the brackets but im unsure of how to fix them
    }


    System.out.println("The lowest scoring hurler was " + hurlerArray[findLow(hurlerArray)].getName());// error with my code here I  think it is in the method
}

}//end of class
```

I know the nyName, myGoalsScored, myPointsScored is incorrect but can anyone explain why?

This is the class page that accompanies it

```
public class Hurler
{

private String name;
private int goalsScored;
private int pointsScored;


public Hurler() //constructor default
{
    name ="";
    goalsScored = 0;
    pointsScored = 0;
}

public Hurler(String myName, int myGoalsScored, int myPointsScored) // specific constructor 
{
    name = myName;
    goalsScored = myGoalsScored;
    pointsScored = myPointsScored;

}

//get and set name
public String getMyName()
{
    return name;
}

    public void setName(String myName)
{
    name = myName;
}

//get and set goals scored
public int getGoalsScored()
{
    return goalsScored;
}

public void setGoalsScored(int myGoalsScored)
{
    goalsScored = myGoalsScored;
}

// get and set points scored
public int getPointsScored()
{
    return pointsScored;
}

public void setPointsScored(int myPointsScored)
{
    pointsScored = myPointsScored;
}

public int totalPoints(int myGoalsScored, int myPointsScored)
{
    int oneGoal = 3;
    int onePoint = 1; 
    int totalPoints = ((goalsScored * oneGoal) + (pointsScored * onePoint));
    {
        return totalPoints;
    }
}
```

}//end of class

Comment: What does `totalPoints ()` do?Can you post the code for it?

Comment: added the accompaning class page!

Comment: is it a big issue to fix do you think?

Comment: There are several issues... Problem 1: Is there a reason for the second "for" loop that iterates over the value of "int j"? That might be part of the problem. Problem 2: The "totalPoints" method is defined with two arguments (which it does not even use). Get rid of those two arguments in the method definition. Problem 3: In your main method, you are replacing all of the Hurlers in your array after you just defined them all... Is this on purpose? This actually shouldn't be working with the code provided since the three variables "MyName, MyGoalsScored, MyPointsScored" are not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

1. You call totalPoints() without parameters while method totalPoints(int, int) in Hurler class expects two int parameters.
2. Objects MyName, MyGoalsScored, MyPointsScored are not declared at all.
3. You call getName() method, while in Hurler class you do not have one. There is method getMyName(), maybe you want to call that one.